# Change to profile not propagating to all Stack Exchange communities

Tags: support, status-completed, profile-page, profile-sync

I have just been on Stack Overflow and changed my profile, then clicked:

> Save and copy changes to all Stack Exchange communities

But although the changes pick up on some communities (Super User) on others my profile still stays the same as it used to be (Role-playing Games).

I suppose I could go back there and change all the information they have about me manually but I was wondering if there is a problem with the software or if it's an issue with something I'm doing.

Does anybody know?

Pics of issue (with time and date):

[image: Role-playing Game Picture]

[image: Super User Picture]

Comment: I don't see any difference between your Super User profile and RPG profile. What exactly did you change?

Comment: I added pictures to the question.

Comment: I see. Weird indeed.

Comment: I still got the old stuff on the Role-play network.

Comment: Yes, no doubt something is off here, hopefully a dev will arrive and take a look. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The data looks legit, so what probably happened was following:

1. you edited your about me description on SO and clicked "Save changes just for this community",
2. your StackOverflow profile got a site specific override for about me
3. you then came back and edit your display name (Amy McBride -> Amy T McBride), and clicked "Save and copy *changes* to all StackExchange communities"
4. only display name gets propagated as a network default (wiping out previously existing site specific overrides), which is correct, since it's the only *change* that happened

So in order to propagate your description across the network from SO, you have to change it a bit, and then click the "Save and copy changes ..." button. Note that there's a slight delay for the changes to propagate to your profile page in other communities. However you should see them immediately if you go to the edit profile page there.

Comment: I was sure that "Save and copy changes to all StackExchange communities" copy everything, without really checking what changed. Glad to see it's smarter than that! :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard it used to do that, with the result that changing your display name could wipe out your carefully-written per-site "about" blocks.  They fixed that somewhere along the line, so now only the things you actually changed in *this* edit propagate.